# Getting `Any` instead of Seq[DataFrame]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to slightly improve the following code:

```
val filePathsList = Seq("path_1","path_2)

var seqdf = filePathsList.map(path => {
        try {
          sqlContext.read.format("json").load(path)
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace()
        }
})
```

Now `seqdf` has the type `Any`, because I added `try ... catch`. I need `seqdf` to be of the type `Seq[DataFrame]` while maintaining `try ... catch` for cases when `json` file does not exist at a `path`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a flatMap and Option to automatically get rid of invalid values

```
var seqdf = filePathsList.flatMap(path => {
        try {
            Some(sqlContext.read.format("json").load(path))
        } catch { case e: Exception => 
            e.printStackTrace()
            None
        }
})
```

If you don't really care about the stack trace, then a more succinct version is shown below

```
var seqdf = filePathsList.flatMap(path => {
        Try(sqlContext.read.format("json").load(path)).toOption
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Scala `Try` and `getOrElse` which more efficient than Java `try` `catch`. And you can return empty `dataframe` if the path is not found.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

var seqdf = filePathsList.map(path => {
  Try(
    sqlContext.read.format("json").load(path)
  ) getOrElse Seq.empty[String].toDF()
})
```

Hope this is helpful